# Why don't multiple decrement operators work in C when they work in C++?

Tags: c++, c, operators, decrement

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27672749/6850771) question and trying out some of the code:

```
int x = 100;

while ( 0 <-------------------- x )
{
    printf("%d ", x);
}
```

I attempted to compile with `gcc` and got the following error:

```
file.c: In function 'main':
file:c:10:27: error: lvalue required as decrement operand
 while ( 0 <-------------------- x )
```

But compiling with `g++` works. Why is this code valid in C++ but not C?

Comment: Because C and C++ are two different languages. In other words, C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: Because the downto operator `<--` can be stretched in C++ many times if you want to decrease faster: `<----` is downtoby2, `<--------------------` is downtoby10

Comment: @chqrlie Circular reasoning. Q: Why does water come out of my tap and not Pepsi? A: Because taps can be used to easily access water.

Comment: In C, you can work around it by writing `while (0 < (x -= 10))`.

Comment: Alternately, to keep the fancy style of the OP, `while (0 < (x +=-+-+- 10))`

Comment: @chqrlie You didn't tell me that either. You merely restated what the question was asking about.

Comment: The thread you posted needs a big sign with sarcasm/irony/humor above it, most things there are not to be used. I would consider @dan04 's style `while (0 < (x -= 10))` superior in any way.... Just because things are possible doesn't mean they are good.

Comment: @jamesqf That `--a` return `a` looks like a sound choice to me.

Comment: This decrementing style is seriously one of the ugliest things I've ever seen. *washes eyes with acid*

Comment: _"But compiling with g++ works. Why is this code valid in C++ but not C?"_ - Just because g++ (or any other compiler) accepts it doesn't automatically mean it's valid C++ code. Never ever forget that.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr It's just [controlling decrement speed based on arrow length.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27672749/7292857)

Comment: @dan04 I think your suggestion `while (0 < (x -= 10))` is better because it is more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Kami Kaze: I even find that confusing.  Clearer to write "while ((x -= 10)  > 0)".  At least I normally think left to right - maybe people from cultures whose native languages are written right to left would disagree.  And another question: for what value of n is it more efficient to decrement n times, than to subtract n?  My guess is not more than 2.

Comment: @jamesqf I won't bother discussing if you should "reverse" the statement. It is just the same. Both are better than `--------------i` though

Comment: @Redesign and it should be punished with copying the C++ standard by hand, if you ever write this in a program. I hope you did understand that the whole thing is just a joke.

Comment: @KamiKaze I **certainly** did.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In C, `--x` is a value, not an lvalue. Its effect is to decrement `x`, and evaluate to the newly assigned value of `x`. Since `--x` is not an lvalue, it cannot be decremented.

In C++, `--x` is an lvalue, not an rvalue. Its effect is to decrement `x`, and evaluate to `x` as an lvalue. Since `--x` is an lvalue again, it can be decremented again.

The reason why it makes sense for `--x` to be an lvalue in C++ is because C++ introduced reference types. Given

```
void f(int &);
int i;
```

it may make sense to call `f(--i)`, which passes `i` by reference after decrementing it.

Since C doesn't have reference types, there's little point in `--i` being an lvalue. Historically, it never was, and unlike C++, C never gained a compelling reason to change the rules.

Note that C++ required more extensive changes than making `--x` an lvalue to actually let it work. Making `--x` an lvalue, without anything else, would make `--x` undefined behaviour, because there would not be a sequence point between the modification to `x` and the subsequent lvalue-to-value conversion. Even more clearly so for `----x`. C++ had to modify the sequencing rules to make it work. In C, modifications to the sequencing rules might cause problems for existing compilers to conform to the new rules, so such modifications would likely be rejected unless there's a big benefit.

Comment: You could still want to say something like `f(&--x)`. I'm not sure I buy your reason why "there's no point" in C.

Comment: @KerrekSB Fair point, but there's still little point. I'd say `f(&--x)` is less likely to be what someone actually wants to write than `f(--x)`. Regardless, C also has a problem that changes to the rules would be problematic for existing implementations, I added a bit on that.

Comment: C++ did not require any sequencing changes to make `--x` an lvalue.  The pre-C++11 rule about sequence points pertains to reads and writes, not to lvalue-to-rvalue conversions.

Comment: The behaviour of `----x` changed in C++11 (well-defined after, undefined before)

Comment: If you really want to do `f(&--x)` in C, you can do `f((--x,&x))`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the historical background here, but IMO the most compelling case for making assignment return an lvalue is that for user-defined classes, you really don't want to return a copy. Then everything else is just consistency.

Comment: @T.C. That comment probably depends to be its own answer, although I suppose one could argue that the rules don't have to be the same for built-in types and classes that overload `++`.

Comment: @T.C. What you say makes sense as well, and if you or someone else were to say you do remember that that's the real reason, I'd believe you. This is what I think I remember reading at one point, but I could be misremembering, or I could have read it from someone else who didn't know the history either.

Comment: People who write code like `f(&--x)` should get fired immediately.